# Mozilla Thunderbird 3.1.9 - not compatible with GMail conversation view addon?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, firefox, email-client

A lot of time I already spent to find a suitable plugin (or addon) for mozilla thunderbird gmail conversation view.

I found this : https://addons.mozilla.org/af/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/

but it is just not compatible with my thunder bird version..

what I need to solve is:

- if one of my friends sends an email to me and another 10 friends. and everyone write a response. I can not read all in one mail (one by one). But I have to open 10 new emails. and is very hard to look over all.

so can I have it like in Gmail?
Do I have to install older version? is this possible and what are disadvantages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well... would that be a problem, to have a 3.x version portable Thunderbird installed for this? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) extension from Mozilla to force the plugin to work on Thunderbird 3.  However, that will only remove the version check from the extension.  If it is truly incompatible it still will not work or may even crash Thunderbird.

Have you tried using the *Threads* display mode that comes with Thunderbird?  You can find it in the *View* menu.  It works a lot like Gmail conversations and there are many extensions to customize it.

Comment: I tested it, I successful installed it, but it is the same. no gmail conversation.  yes I have threads all. it is ok, but is very annoying to get 10 new emails with the same topic.